# SEO Tweaking dating website / user profiles

Tags: seo, google, ranking

i am running the social dating website called Latte42 and i can't seem to rank for the Keywords I'm after. I want to rank for things like "meet new people", "find friends" but somehow rank for things like "starbucks" and several other Cafe and Places because i have a index where you can chose from places to meet people.
I also rank for keywords like "31 years old" it's because google does index pages like user profiles.

- My question is, should i prevent google from indexing such pages and profiles?
- Would that make the "other" keywords i want to index more relevant?

Comment: Isn't it better if i keep the link so that people can actually see, how my site "does not" perform? :)

Comment: not necessary, and if the link *was* left in, it would smack of you attempting to build links surreptitiously.

Comment: Ah, that was clearly not my intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, should i prevent google from indexing such pages and profiles?

No. Every page you have indexed is another way for people to find you in search. Being visible for long tail search phrases isn't a bad thing. Their volume can really add up.

Not to mention every page Google finds to your site is another page where it can count links for your pages. Internal linking is often overlooked and can have an impact on rankings. PageRank is passed and anchor text in these links can only help you.

> Would that make the "other" keywords i want to index more relevant?

No. You don't rank well for those phrases because you aren't relevant enough for those terms. Just because you rank well for one term it doesn't preclude you from ranking well for another term. A page can rank well for "social dating" and "meet new people" at the same time.

So, if you're not ranking well for those broader and more popular phrases, it's because there is more competition and they are ahead of you in the SEO game. The more sites competing for a search term the more difficult it is going to be to rank well for it.

If you want to rank well for those terms you will need to make sure your pages are optimized and you need to acquire quality incoming links to your pages. Pages from related sites that rank well is ideal but any site related to yours is good to have.

If you want to make sure your site is properly optimized read up on [SEO on this website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo?sort=votes&pagesize=50). If you have any specific questions about SEO that hasn't been covered here yet definitely ask and we'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hello John Conde, thank you very much first of all. Yes indeed, i have an approach where i try to rank for terms like "Starbucks Akihabara" for example Starbucks in japan, where i could may find some people who would join my website, they are interested in drinking coffee and maybe dating? But i can't even come close to terms like "meet people" although the sites ranking in the top 10 are very very low quality content websites. 
How can i improve that? As a new player, how could i get new and juicy links? That's not an option i think. :(